# Mesh won't cooperate with armature

Tags: animation, armature

I am trying to animate a model that I've made that consists of multiple meshes that have been joined together. However, whenever I try to pose the model, rather than the entirety of the joined mesh moving with the armature it makes all of the loose parts move independently (as seen in the picture below).

I really don't want to have to redo the model in order to make all of it a single mesh, and I also don't want to have to go through and connect each of the loose parts by their vertices just for it to be one whole mesh.

Is there a way around this or am I going to have to do one of the options above?

Thanks for the help!

[image][image]

Comment: maybe try to parent with automatic weight before joining the different parts. If it stills doesn't work well, you need to give it some corections in weight paint mode, or with the Assign button under the vertex groups list in the Object Data panel

Comment: Joining the mesh will not help. To me it's most likely just that your mesh weights isn't setup correctly. Also, make sure you have some edge loops on those cylinders where you need them to bend around the knees bones.